# Lift up characteristic class to chain complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, derived-categories, characteristic-classes, chain-complexes

In derived category, there is a slogan, "cohomology is bad, chain complex is good". In the theory of characteristic classes, we could associate a vector bundle to cohomology classes of the base space.

Can we lift up (naturally) these cohomology classes to an actual complex?

I am particularly interested in Chern class and vector bundle over an algebraic variety over complex numbers.

Comment: You can realize Chern classes as obstruction classes (obstructions to sections of the associated complex frame bundle), which themselves have a direct geometric definition as obstruction cocycles. Actually explicitly specifying these obstruction cocyles is more difficult.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but in the slogan it's cohomology **groups** that are bad. Cohomology classes are fine (in fact they can be interpreted as maps between complexes)

Comment: @DenisNardin You're right, I misinterpret the slogan a little bit. What I want is like Tobias said, lifting up the cohomology group to a chain complex, e.g. de Rham or simplicial, and then looking for particular nice representatives of characteristic classes in that complex.

Comment: @userabc That's kind of the opposite of what the slogan is suggesting to do, but in Chern-Weil theory you construct explicit representatives for the Chern classes in the deRham complex, and that has some applications.

Comment: As Tobias mentions, obstruction cocycles is the formulation that's natural at the cochain complex level.  But depending on exactly what you want, you might not like this formalism -- it requires working rather explicitly with the tangent bundle.  Perhaps tell us what kind of thing you are looking for.

Comment: @RyanBudney There are some natural projective bundles over (smooth subvariety of) partial flag varieties that I would like know its cohomology ring. For example is $G/B \rightarrow G/P$, where G is a semisimple algebraic group, (though $H^*(G/B)$ is well-known). It suffices to find chern classes for the vector bundles by Leray-Hirsch. To do actual computation, one way is to find an explicit representatives of a suitable cohomology theory. Since both base space and total space are really nice space, are there any models better than the obstruction cocycles? Sorry if this question is too vague.